# A special case of the JC where the degrees are equal

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $p,q \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q):=p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$.
Assume that $\deg(p)=\deg(q)$ (the total degree, also called the $(1,1)$-degree).

> **Claim:** In this special case (equal degrees) it follows that $f: (x,y) \mapsto (p,q)$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Please, I would like to make sure that I am not missing something,
and the above claim (which I have not seen in articles) is indeed true.

If $f: (x,y) \mapsto (p,q)$ is not an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, then (by a result that I think I have seen in van den Essen's book, perhaps due to a result of [Nagata](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39334102.pdf) and [Lang](https://ac.els-cdn.com/002240499190128O/1-s2.0-002240499190128O-main.pdf?_tid=a2fc385e-b038-4fb3-9836-124ae4492f9e&acdnat=1548797726_851c9c4cfadc514cf3454c74276573b8)) there exists an automorphism $g$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that:

- $\deg(p)=\deg(g(p))$.
- $\deg(q)=\deg(g(q))$.
- $\deg(g(p))=(a+b)n > (a+b)m=\deg(g(q))$

(since the $(1,1)$-leading term of $g(p)$ is $\lambda x^{an}y^{bn}$ and the $(1,1)$-leading term of $g(q)$ is $\mu x^{am}y^{bm}$, $\lambda,\mu \in k^{\times}$).

Then $\deg(p)>\deg(q)$, contrary to our assumption.

**Remark:** Now I see that there is a problem with my claim, since every endomorphism we can bring to a form with equal degrees (just multiply with an appropriate automorphism such as $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y,x-y)$), and then it would follow that the JC is true.. this seems too easy to be a valid proof for the two-dimensional JC. So the quoted result (concerning the existence of such $g$ etc.) should be wrong? (Probably I misunderstood the quoted result).

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Actually, there is no contradiction, since the result I was talking about is Theorem 5.11 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6100v2.pdf, which deals with an irreducible pair $(p,q)$, and as such it cannot have $\deg(p)=\deg(q)$, by Proposition 3.8.